# Вывести у каждого автора названия его книг

Tags: java, массивы

Даны два массива одного размера – список фамилий авторов (фамилии авторов могут
повторяться) и соответствующий ему список названий написанных ими книг. Указать, количество книг каждого автора. Отсортировать и вывести на экран список авторов по
алфавиту и у каждого автора указать названия его книг.

Проблема не знаю как к авторам добавить названия книг в выводе. Ещё у одного автора может быть несколько книг

```
public class arr {

    public static int compareStrings(String word1, String word2)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < Math.min(word1.length(), word2.length()); i++)
        {
            if((int)word1.charAt(i) != (int)word2.charAt(i))//comparing unicode values
                return (int)word1.charAt(i) - (int)word2.charAt(i);
        }
        if(word1.length() != word2.length())//smaller word is occurs at the beginning of the larger word
            return word1.length() - word2.length();
        else
            return 0;
    }
    public static String[] stringArraySort(String[] words)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < words.length - 1; i++)
        {
            for(int j = i+1; j < words.length; j++)
            {
                if(compareStrings(words[i], words[j]) > 0)//words[i] is greater than words[j]
                {
                    String temp = words[i];
                    words[i] = words[j];
                    words[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return words;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        
        Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
        String[] array = {"Пушкин", "Пушкин", "Гоголь"};
        String[] array2 = {"Капитанская дочка", "Дубровский", "Вий"};
        for(String s : array){

            if(result.containsKey(s)){
                //if the map contain this key then just increment your count
                result.put(s, result.get(s)+1);
            }else{
                //else just create a new node with 1
                result.put(s, 1);
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println(result);
        String[] sortedArr = stringArraySort(array);

        for(int i = 0; i < sortedArr.length; i++)
            System.out.print(sortedArr[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если стоит задача отсортировать второй массив в том же порядке, что и были отсортированы автора в первом массиве с использованием "своего" метода сортировки `stringArraySort`, то это достаточно просто реализовать, добавив соответствующий параметр.  Кроме того, метод `stringArraySort` не обязан возвращать значения, т.е. у него может быть тип возврата `void`, как у стандартного метода `Arrays::sort`.

Вариант такого решения:

```java
public static void stringArraySort(String[] words, String[] titles) {
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length - 1; i++) {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < words.length; j++) {
            if (compareStrings(words[i], words[j]) > 0) {
                // переставим авторов
                String temp = words[i];
                words[i] = words[j];
                words[j] = temp;
                // переставим произведения
                temp = titles[i];
                titles[i] = titles[j];
                titles[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
// ...
stringArraySort(array, array2);

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(array[i] + " " + array2[i]);
}
```

Вывод:

```
Гоголь Вий
Пушкин Дубровский
Пушкин Капитанская дочка
```

Впрочем, в данном случае не гарантируется отсортированность *произведений*, например, для входных данных:

```java
String[] array = {"Пушкин", "Пушкин", "Пушкин", "Гоголь", "Гоголь"};
String[] array2 = {"Повести Белкина", "Капитанская дочка", "Дубровский", "Мёртвые души", "Вий"};
```

результат:

```
Гоголь Мёртвые души
Гоголь Вий
Пушкин Дубровский
Пушкин Повести Белкина
Пушкин Капитанская дочка
```

---

Однако, проще и корректнее было бы использовать стандартные сортированные коллекции и мапы для решения такой задачи.

- `SortedMap` / `TreeMap` - получить мапу, отсортированную по ключам (авторам)
- в качестве значений в такой мапе следует хранить отсортированные множества произведений `SortedSet` / `TreeSet` (если в исходных данных отсутствуют дубликаты названий или ими можно пренебречь).
- для получения количества произведений достаточно использовать метод `Collection::size`.

Тогда также не понадобится использовать самописные методы сортировки.

Такую мапу легко получить при помощи Stream API:

```java
SortedMap<String, SortedSet<String>> result = IntStream.range(0, array.length)
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        i -> array[i],
        TreeMap::new,
        Collectors.mapping(i -> array2[i], Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new))
    ));

result.forEach((author, works) -> System.out.println(
    author + ", произведений: " + works.size() + "; перечень: " + String.join(", ", works)
));
```

Впрочем, более классический вариант с циклом может выглядеть "короче" с использованием `Map::computeIfAbsent`:

```java
SortedMap<String, SortedSet<String>> result = new TreeMap<>();

for (int i = 0, n = array.length; i < n; i++) {
    result.computeIfAbsent(array[i], author -> new TreeSet<>()).add(array2[i]);
}
```

Результат в обоих случаях:

```
Гоголь, произведений: 2; перечень: Вий, Мёртвые души
Пушкин, произведений: 3; перечень: Дубровский, Капитанская дочка, Повести Белкина
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогли очень!

Answer (score 0):

Такое решение:

```
String[] authors = { "Пушкин", "Пушкин", "Гоголь" };
String[] books = { "Капитанская дочка", "Дубровский", "Вий" };

Map<String, List<String>> authorBookListMap = new TreeMap<>(); // Класс TreeMap автоматически сортирует ключи в алфавитном порядке

for (int i = 0; i < authors.length; i++) {
    String author = authors[i];
    String book = books[i];

    authorBookListMap.computeIfAbsent(author, author_ -> new ArrayList<>()).add(book); // Сбор данных в карту, где ключ - имя автора, а значение - список книг
}

// Для удобства вывода, приводим в следующий вид карту
Set<Entry<String, List<String>>> authorBookListEntrySet = authorBookListMap.entrySet();

for (Entry<String, List<String>> authorBookListEntry : authorBookListEntrySet) {
    String author = authorBookListEntry.getKey();
    List<String> bookList = authorBookListEntry.getValue();

    System.out.println("Автор: " + author + "; Названия книг: " + String.join(", ", bookList) + "; Количество книг: " + bookList.size());
}
```

Пример ручной сортировки в предыдущем ответе.

Comment: Постарайтесь оставлять более развернутые ответы (объясните ваш код, например).